# How to get back the layout after setting the visibility to GONE in android

Tags: android, android-layout

xml-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout two is hidden after pressing a button with View.GONE, I want the layout two back when I swipe down on the screen, how can I do it, swipe down detection and getting the layout back.

Comment: Does my answer help? Or were you trying to figure out how to pick up a scrolling event?

Comment: yes trying to figure out how to pick up a scrolling a event @AdamJohns

Comment: Is the "swipe down" detection you are referring to a gesture you want to recognize or is there actually a listview or something you want to scroll down?

Comment: Its a gesture @AdamJohns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
yourRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.Visible);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `yourView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` on the View you want to make visible in your on swipe down method.